# using cookie to uniquely identify users

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

i'm creating an asp.net website and i want to implement an almost accurate hit counter. as i understood the online solutions based on SessionStart are not very accurate, so i was thinking that maybe i can put a cookie on users machine and on each SessionStart check for existance of that cookie, if it exists then don't count that request, otherwise add one up to Cache["hits"] and create a new hit cookie on target machine. can it be done like this?

```
public void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("hitCookie");
    if(cookie == null)
    {
        object hitsObj = Cache["hits"];
        if(hitsObj != null)
        {
            int hits = Convert.ToInt32(hitsObj);
            Cache["hits"] = hits + 1;
            cookie = new HttpCookie("hitCookie");
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

if you're thinking that the cookies might be disabled on users machine then remember that asp.net membership is not gonna work by default too.

**update:** cookies are much more reliable than other methods for counting visitors and not the **MEMBERS** of your site, and yes you can delete them and i think in that way it would be ok to count the user twice. at least i'm not counting any bot or crawler that starts a new session.

Comment: You are wrong in your last assumption http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx. Also with your code if i access your website after clearing my cache it will be counted as two hits

Comment: i did mention by default! so if you change the <sessionstate> that's another story. also my solution is primary, if it was permanent then i wouldn't have posted this question.